# Unity add more time whenever you score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a timer.cs that has 30 sec and i want to add like 4 more sec whenever i get a point. The script that detects is ScoringSystem.cs

ScoringSystem.cs

```
public class ScoringSystem : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject scoreText;
    public static int theScore;

    void Update()
    {   
        scoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Score: " + theScore; 
    }
}
```

Timer.cs

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string LevelToLoad;
    private static float timer = 30f;
    private Text timerSeconds;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        timerSeconds = GetComponent<Text> ();
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        timerSeconds.text = timer.ToString("f0");
        if (timer <= 0) 
        {    
            timer = 30f;    
            Application.LoadLevel (LevelToLoad); 
        }
    }
}
```

There's the update on how the ScoringSystem works.   https://prnt.sc/t7xk8l

Comment: Can you add the code as well. Where you add to theScore variable.

Comment: hi again i am again using another account. theScore variable is on the first code

Comment: Yeah I saw that I mean is the Code where you add to theScore variable still the same. Because if you wanted to increase time you should do it there.

Comment: That's the whole code and the only place where i use TheScore variable

Comment: How do you increase theScore then?

Comment: The void Update does that

Comment: OH OK i found out i have another one that adds the points i will edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code under the if-statement in the CollectPoint.cs:

```
Timer.timer += 4;
```

And change the timer variable from `private static float timer = 30f;` to `public static float timer = 30f;`

Comment: CollectPoint.cs under the if-statement.

Comment: `Timer.timer' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: make it a public static float instead of a private static float

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help.

Comment: I have a certain problem that is not related to the question, but when the timer ends i go to the game over screen, however the mouse get's stuck in the middle of the screen. How do i fix that?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code. Is Unity printing out any Error Messages and are you doing somethign with the mouse codewise (for example Screen.lockCursor = true)?

Comment: I just have a script saying  void Start () {
  
  Cursor.visible = true;

 }

Comment: What happens when you remove that line of code. Because the cursor is visible by default. So making it visible probably means you are making it invisible somewhere in your code?

Comment: I removed the whole script and it still stays stuck

Comment: Are you affecting your mouse somewhere else in the script?

Comment: And I would just try to add `Screen.lockCursor = false;` and `Cursor.visible = true;` to the Start() Object of one of the scripts in the GameOver Scene

Comment: Like i said i deleted the entire script and that was the only place

Comment: Okay then try the second thing I wrote (to add the 2 lines of code in the Game Over Scene)

Comment: No problem, but next time please start a new question so if someone has the same problem they can find the answer easily :D